# Optimizing images

Tags: html, css, image

While making a webpage I've noticed a huge decrease in performance(client side) when I've added more rows to a table. Each row in my table consists of the same 4-5 different 32x32 icons (links to actions) and about 100 characters. When there were 10 rows, the webpage run fluently - scrolling and jQuery animations were smooth. Now that my table has 100+ rows (pagination is not an option), the animations are really slow and rough.
Is there a way to optimize not the images themselves, but the code, to raise performance?

Right now I have images in  tags. Will it make any difference if I will change them to  with background-image? Will the browser be less loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If images are the problem, it is likely because the client is trying to re-download the images for each row, which is very inefficient even though the images are small.  You can test if this is true with a tool such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) by checking if you get a whole bunch of the same requests every time you reload the page.

If this is the problem, look into [CSS sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp).  With this method, you can deliver 1 image to the client, and this one image will be used to render all of your icons on all your rows.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, that what I was worrying about, but it doesn't mean much to me, as the problem is the backend of the system. What bothers me more is if the same images are stored separately in RAM, I just need some explanation of the methods browser uses. What about the sprites - if the image is downloaded once, does the client store it once or as many times as we are referring to it in the markup/CSS? And thank you for the Fiddler tool, will look into it.

Comment: @Vlakarados:  As long as the URL you are using to load/retrieve the image is constant, the client browser should be smart enough to store the image once and reuse it as necessary when painting elements into the window.